# Private constructor and object literals

Tags: typescript

I am trying to implement the builder pattern to enforce that objects are only created using the builder.

```
class Product {
    name: string
    price?: number
    discount?: number
    
    private constructor(name: string){
        this.name = name
    }

    static builder(name: string): ProductBuilder {
        return new ProductBuilder(new Product(name))
    }
}

class ProductBuilder {
    private product: Product

    constructor(product: Product) {
        this.product = product
    }

    withPrice(price?: number) {
        this.product.price = price;
    }

    // other builder methods

    build(): Product {
        // Perform validation

        return this.product
    }
}

// This works (as expected)
let productBuilder = Product.builder('PC')
productBuilder.withPrice(125.6)
let product = productBuilder.build()


// But this also works!!. 
let items: Product[] = [
    {
        name: 'Laptop'
    }
]
```

As you can see, I am able to create a list of `Product` objects directly, which should not be the case.

I learned that `items` are created using object literals and not the `new` keyword. However, I find it hard to understand how `items` are created.

How can I modify my implementation to enforce that `Product` objects can only be created using the builder pattern?

Comment: You can't. Really there's little point your `Product` being a class, it could just be an interface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TypeScript types are really just type hints, since the underlying run-time language is JavaScript which is a weakly and dynamically typed language.

You could even get a broken object as a string and make it "product", like this (don't try this at home):

```js
const myProduct: Product = "definitely not a product" as unknown as Product;
```

You can find some insights on how to enforce the type in [this Medium article](https://medium.com/weekly-webtips/how-to-enforce-typescript-types-in-the-runtime-environment-3564ae33a792), however, every check you can do is basically [duck typing checks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing), and if the consumer manages to build an object that passes all the type checks, there will be no way to tell whether it comes from your builder or not.